# Journey Logic Problems

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm getting stuck in a journey implementation. I get the feeling I'm overcomplicating this but I can't seem to breakthrough here.

I'm building 3 journeys that begin with their own filtered entry sources. From each journey, depending on the engagement within the emails, contacts will have the ability to jump to another journey and exit from their current.

I'm planning to update the contact in the data extension when they reach a certain path depending on their engagement and that updated field will be used to exit them and enter them into another journey.

My test exited them, but failed to enter them into the next journey. I have this data connected in the data designer to filter them at the entry level.

Does this sound like a good solution for this type of journey or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Journey Builder does not detect updates to existing rows in a Data Extension.

This means the scenario described - with the Contact Update activity would not be enough for the second or third Journey to notice that some subscriber attributes have changed in order to inject it to the corresponding follow-up Journey.

There are couple of ways to do what you're after, the easiest would probably be to use Automation Studio that uses SQL to add a **new row** to a Journey-specific Entry data extension.